# All combination of 2 lists in ansible

Tags: sorting, ansible

I have 2 variables as a list in ansible

```
host_list:
    - 1.1.1.1
    - 2.2.2.2

port_list:
    - 443
    - 80
```

and I want to get the 3rd variable as a list of lists:

```
all_comb = [[1.1.1.1, 443], [1.1.1.1, 80], [2.2.2.2, 443], [2.2.2.2, 80]]
```

How can i get it in Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `with_nested` or a `query('nested', listA, listB)` loop, see both implementations below:

**with_nested:**

```
- name: merge lists
  set_fact:
    merged_list: "{{ merged_list|default([]) + [item] }}"
  with_nested:
  - "{{ host_list }}"
  - "{{ port_list }}"

- name: display result
  debug:
    var: merged_list
```

**with query:**

```
- name: merge lists
  set_fact:
    merged_list: "{{ merged_list|default([]) + [item] }}"
  loop: "{{ query('nested', host_list, port_list) }}"

- name: display result
  debug:
    var: merged_list
```

**result of the latter:**

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [merge lists] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'1.1.1.1', 443])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'1.1.1.1', 80])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'2.2.2.2', 443])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'2.2.2.2', 80])

TASK [display result] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "merged_list": [
        [
            "1.1.1.1", 
            443
        ], 
        [
            "1.1.1.1", 
            80
        ], 
        [
            "2.2.2.2", 
            443
        ], 
        [
            "2.2.2.2", 
            80
        ]
    ]
}
```

cheers

Comment: glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) filter

```yaml
all_comb: "{{ host_list|product(port_list) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
all_comb:
  - [1.1.1.1, 443]
  - [1.1.1.1, 80]
  - [2.2.2.2, 443]
  - [2.2.2.2, 80]
```